# How to save autocomplete and date type fields while adding node programmatically?

Tags: entities, nodes

I am creating a node programmatically and I have a field which is autocomplete and has number of values set to unlimited.

In the code for adding the node programmatically ,the code is as given below

```
    $node->field_user[]['value'] = $user->name;
       $node->field_time[]['value'] = date('m-d-Y H:i', REQUEST_TIME);
  $trans_node->field_download_flag[0]['value'] = 'YES';
```

So after programmatically creating a view when I check into the 'find content' place I see a node being generated but when I click on the link(where the content title is )( not on the edit link) , I cannot see the field_user in the view list

**field_time**
**type**: date 
**widget** : popup calendar
**no of values** : unlimited. 

**field_date**
**type**: Entity Reference 
**widget** : Autocomplete 
**no of values** : unlimited.

**field_flag**
**type**: boolean 
**widget** : checkbox/radiobutton 
**no of values** : unlimited.

I think the code for field_user should be as

```
$node->field_user[]['target_id'] =  $user->name;
```

but still i am getting error that is WSOD

Comment: Have you tried : $node->field_user['und'][]['target_id']

Comment: Can I assign user->name to target_id or should I assign  it to $user->uid ?

Comment: target_id is for an uid reference

Comment: it works with $node->field_user['und'][]['target_id'] ..and now what about time field?

Comment: same :$node->field_time['und'][]['value']. Use devel module and the dpm or dpr function to display how node object is structured. Devel is essential :)

Comment: Is this Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: Drupal 7 can u pls let me know about the boolean and date fields ?

Comment: What about them?

Comment: Like for field_user the format is field_user['und'][]['target_id'] then what about the rest of them..

Comment: For boolean the column name is 'value', for date the potential names are 'value', 'value2', and another one to do with the timezone (can't recall the name off the top of my head)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

```
$node->field_user['und'][]['target_id']
```

and

```
$node->field_time['und'][]['value']
```

is the good way

Comment: for field_time i getting error .. even after using $node->field_time['und'][]['value'] ??

Comment: pls check the updated question I have also added boolean field...

Comment: enable devel module you'll be able to see the node object structure

Comment: is it present in the core>

Comment: lol no, i can't do it for u

Comment: @user13198 This code is correct for entity reference and date fields. For boolean fields, use 'value' as the column name, and use 1 or 0 as the value

Comment: one last question for this post could you pls tell me am I right using the format field_user_nid['und'][0]['nid'] for nid field ??

Comment: be careful: user is 'uid', and node is 'nid'

Comment: @pico34 For the References module that's true, for the EntityReference module it's `target_id` across the board